# Lua error for WoW addon (Tukui)

Tags: lua, string-concatenation, world-of-warcraft

I don't have a lot of coding experience, did some C a few years ago, so that helps, but Lua handles things a bit differently, so I can't keep track.

I sometimes (not always) get this error when a friend or guildy logs into the game:

```
Date: 2013-06-14 16:57:57
ID: -1
Error occured in: Global
Count: 4
Message: ..\AddOns\Tukui\scripts\chat.lua line 335:
        attempt to concatenate upvalue 'classColor' (a nil value)
Debug:
  [C]: ?
   Tukui\scripts\chat.lua:335: AddMessage()
   ..\FrameXML\ChatFrame.lua:2755: ChatFrame_MessageEventHandler()
   ..\FrameXML\ChatFrame.lua:2491: ChatFrame_OnEvent()
   ...s\WIM\Libs\LibChatHandler-1.0\LibChatHandler-1.0.lua:281:
   ...s\WIM\Libs\LibChatHandler-1.0\LibChatHandler-1.0.lua:252
   ...s\WIM\Libs\LibChatHandler-1.0\LibChatHandler-1.0.lua:308:
   ...s\WIM\Libs\LibChatHandler-1.0\LibChatHandler-1.0.lua:296
```

I have to do a reload of the ui after this happens to be able to see chat text again for that person.

Line 335 in that .lua file is this:

```
text = replace(text, "^|Hplayer:(.+)|h%[(.+)%]|h", "|Hplayer:%1|h|cff"..classColor.."%2|r|h")
```

Now I've learned that the .. indicates the concatenate function, but that isn't really helping me.

I don't know if this is enough information, but if you need it I can post the whole local function or whatever else is required.

If it makes any difference, I'm running the 3.3.5a WoW client.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a global that gets defined from some other addon in a now deterministic way
While the (classColor or "") will get you rid of the error, you should try and find why that variable (classColor) is sometimes defined and sometimes not. Maybe it happens only for certain classes?

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack would be to just replace

```
..classColor..
```

with

```
..(classColor or "")..
```

where it will select a blank string when `classColor` has no value assigned to it.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that and see if I get rid of the error.

Just to help me learn, can you maybe explain what all this means:
    "^|Hplayer:(.+)|h%[(.+)%]|h"

especially the part between the | |

Comment: @Blazzok Those are forming Lua patter (most possibly). [Here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial) is a guide to Lua patterns. They are similar to regex strings. Here, we are storing the part after `Hplayer:` and inside `h[]` and probably replacing them later; by referring to them as `%1` and `%2`.

Comment: @Blazzok World of Warcraft uses it's own type of escape sequences (though they are started by the pipe `|` character instead of the escape `\ ` character) for special markup like coloring, item links, etc. You can read up there: http://www.wowpedia.org/UI_escape_sequences